# How to ensure OpenVPN connection uses specific DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, mac-osx, openvpn

I'm using OpenVPN through Tunnelblick on MacOS X Lion.

I need to set specific DNS (with local IP, which works only when VPN is up) for the duration of this VPN session only.

I **do not have access to the OpenVPN server configuration.** Only client config. Also, DNS from the server **doesn't work.**

So it works like this: I connect to VPN, go the Network preferences and manually set DNS.
After VPN is disconnected, I switch back to default. It works, but it needs to be **automatic.**

After some exploration I found that OpenVPN up- and down- scripts might help me with that. Unfortunately, I haven't found any specific documentation about how exactly it can be done.

How it can or can't be done? Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: I've also considered ControlPlane app - no luck figuring it out :-)

Comment: @quanta Nice, but I'll have to list all domains - that's too much :-( (We have a few dozens of domains in our developer infrastructure.)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

try adding:

```
# put actual dns name here
dhcp-option DNS 10.11.12.13
```

to your client's config

Comment: Thank you! It worked.
I've stumbled upon `push "dhcp-option DNS 10.11.12.13"` regarding server configs, didn't know how to convert it to client configs.
Thanks again :-)

Comment: this works, but still in openvpn I can see my local DNS still gets pushed: DNS servers '4.2.2.1 4.2.2.2 192.168.0.1' will be used for DNS queries when the VPN is active
                                        NOTE: The DNS servers do not include any free public DNS servers known to Tunnelblick. This may cause DNS queries to fail or be intercepted or falsified even if they are directed through the VPN. Specify only known public DNS servers or DNS servers located on the VPN network to avoid such problems.

Comment: And how, exactly, does one change the Tunnelblick configuration in Mac OS? Is this command line or GUI?

Answer (score 16):

If you (unlike the OP) have access to the OpenVPN server configuration, you can add this option in your OpenVPN `server.conf` if you want to push for all the clients:

```
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

You can change the `8.8.8.8` to your desired DNS.

Comment: OP is clearly saying that he doesn't have access to the server configuration.

Comment: why is this still getting upvotes? clearly the a wrong answer, `push` inside a client conf doesn't work

Comment: BCS "if you have access to the OpenVPN server configuration"

Answer (score 6):

add this to client config file:

```
#ipv4
pull-filter ignore "dhcp-option DNS"
#ipv6
pull-filter ignore "dhcp-option DNS6"
```

Comment: This fixed the 'no internet connectivity detected' issue with many Windows 10 apps (like Word, Excel, Outlook, Store Apps) for me. Was using OpenVPN, traffic routed over VPN with a custom DNS over VPN.

Comment: Just from looking at it it looks like it is ignoring the DNS server that is applied from the server. This means that the client will leak DNS requests outside the tunnel.