# OpenVPN Client connects, but DNS setting are not correct (cannot resolve domain names)

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, openvpn, linux-networking, raspbian

I've an active subscription with `VPNUnlimited`, and they have sent a few settings in order to be able to use `OpenVPN` client with their service. (they have sent me pre-made `.ovpn` files for each of their servers)

the thing is, I've followed a tutorial to setup `OpenVPN` in my raspberry pi, and whenever I start the `OpenVPN` client with the `.ovpn` file, it authenticate and connects successfully.

this looks great but the problem is after a successfull connection, it looks like DNS configuration is not correct as any trial to navigate/ping any domain name fails, although pinging any IP is succeeded, so it's normally state that there is a DNS problem.

disconnecting the session will restore back the ability to resolve domain names normally and use the built-in web browser to browse websites.

I've searched for a while and found that one possible fix is to add the following line (provided from this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/416708/how-to-ensure-openvpn-connection-uses-specific-dns)) to the `client.conf` file in order to force the client to use Google DNS:

`dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8`

but unfortunately it's not working.

this is what is on my screen as a result on connecting to openvpn:
[image]

and this is the `ifconfig` after the connection is established:
[image]

and this is the `ifconfig` result when I disconnect the `OpenVPN` client:
[image]

I hope I could clarify the situation, and if anyone can help me to setup the proper configuration to make my raspberry pi use google DNS (or anything that would work) I would much appreciate it as I can't figure it out yet.

Comment: Please do not post text output as images. Use text and formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The interface settings are fairly unimportant.  Instead - look in   `/etc/resolv.conf`

The OpenVPN client should write this content on connection

> nameserver 8.8.8.8 
>   nameserver 8.8.4.4

and restore your original nameservers on exit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, actually it's not. although I describe the full details of what I'm doing, so I don't know why it's not doing it as it supposed to do.

Comment: @MohammedElSayed perhaps you have some other DNS resolver on the local machine.  Please post the content of ```/etc/resolv.conf```  with and without the VPN connected.

Comment: Actually the problem was that the contents of the file was not changing when the VPn connects, and when I change the DNS to 8.8.8.8 in the `resolv.conf` file, it solved the problem of DNS not resolving, but also not changing between VPN sessions. I really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Are you establishing the VPN as root ?  You might need to tweak permissions to allow a the VPN / non-root user to edit the resolv.conf file.

Comment: I'm establishing it as root.